# Replacing quotation marks with "``" and "''"

Tags: bash, quotes, tex

I have a document containing many `"` marks, but I want to convert it for use in TeX.

TeX uses 2 ` marks for the beginning quote mark, and 2 ' mark for the closing quote mark.

I only want to make changes to these when `"` appears on a single line in an even number (e.g. there are 2, 4, or 6 `"`'s on the line). For e.g.

```
"This line has 2 quotation marks."
--> ``This line has 2 quotation marks.''

"This line," said the spider, "Has 4 quotation marks."
--> ``This line,'' said the spider, ``Has 4 quotation marks.''

"This line," said the spider, must have a problem, because there are 3 quotation marks."
--> (unchanged)
```

My sentences never break across lines, so there is no need to check on multiple lines.

There are few quotes with single quotes, so I can manually change those.

How can I convert these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my one-liner using repeated `sed`'s:

```
cat file.txt | sed -e 's/"\([^"]*\)"/`\1`/g' | sed '/"/s/`/\"/g' | sed -e 's/`\([^`]*\)`/``\1'\'''\''/g'
```

(note: it won't work correctly if there are already back-ticks (`) in the file but otherwise should do the trick)

### **EDIT:**

Removed back-tick bug by simplifying, now works for all cases:

```
cat file.txt | sed -e 's/"\([^"]*\)"/``\1'\'\''/g' | sed '/"/s/``/"/g' | sed '/"/s/'\'\''/"/g'
```

With comments:

```
cat file.txt                           # read file
| sed -e 's/"\([^"]*\)"/``\1'\'\''/g'  # initial replace
| sed '/"/s/``/"/g'                    # revert `` to " on lines with extra "
| sed '/"/s/'\'\''/"/g'                # revert '' to " on lines with extra "
```

Comment: it's not pretty, but I figured out a `sed` 1-liner

Comment: when are bash scripts ever pretty?

Answer (score 3):

This is my one-liner which is works for me:

```
awk -F\" '{if((NF-1)%2==0){res=$0;for(i=1;i<NF;i++){to="``";if(i%2==0){to="'\'\''"}res=gensub("\"", to, 1, res)};print res}else{print}}' input.txt >output.txt
```

And there is long version of this one-liner with comments:

```
{
    FS="\"" # set field separator to double quote
    if ((NF-1) % 2 == 0) { # if count of double quotes in line are even number
        res = $0 # save original line to res variable
        for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) { # for each double quote
            to = "``" # replace current occurency of double quote by ``
            if (i % 2 == 0) { # if its closes quote replace by ''
                to = "''"
            }
            # replace " by to in res and save result to res
            res = gensub("\"", to, 1, res)
        }
        print res # print resulted line
    } else {
        print # print original line when nothing to change
    }
}
```

You may run this script by:

```
awk -f replace-quotes.awk input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `awk`

```
awk '{n=gsub("\"","&")}!(n%2){while(n--){n%2?Q=q:Q="`";sub("\"",Q Q)}}1' q=\' in
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '{
  n=gsub("\"","&") # set n to the number of quotes in the current line
}
!(n%2){ # if there are even number of quotes
  while(n--){ # as long as we have double-quotes
    n%2?Q=q:Q="`" # alternate Q between a backtick and single quote
    sub("\"",Q Q) # replace the next double quote with two of whatever Q is
  }
}1 # print out all other lines untouched' 
q=\' in # set the q variable to a single quote and pass the file 'in' as input
```

#### Using `sed`

```
sed '/^\([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*\)*$/s/"\([^"]*\)"/``\1'\'\''/g' in
```

Comment: I have been gazing over this `awk` solution (and the countless iterations :P) for over 2 hours now and honestly I do not think it could have done any better. Great use of `gsub` to identify number of quotes, nice use of `modulo operator` and fine use of `ternary operator` +1

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'h;s/"\([^"]*\)"/``\1''\'\''/g;/"/g' file
```

Explanation:

- Make a copy of the original line `h`
- Replace pairs of `"`'s ``` s/"\([^"]*\)"/``\1''\'\''/g ```
- Check for odd `"` and if found revert to original line `/"/g`

Comment: I knew it. :) +1. An itsy bitsy explanation would go great with this solution.