# Change `"` quotation marks to latex style

Tags: regex, tex

I'm editing a book in LaTeX and its quotation marks syntax is different from the simple `"` characters. So I want to convert `"quoted text here"` to ``` ``quoted text here'' ```.

I have 50 text files with lots of quotations inside. I tried to write a regular expression to substitute the first `"` with ``` `` ``` and the second `"` with `''`, but I failed. I searched on internet and asked some friends, but I had no success at all. The closest thing I got to replace the first quotation mark is

```
s/"[a-z]/``/g
```

but this is clearly wrong, since

```
"quoted text here"
```

will become

```
``uoted text here"
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your approach. Shouldn't it be the other way round with `s/``/"[a-z]/g`? But then, I think it'll be better with: `s/\`\`(.*?)''/"\1"/g`

Comment: @Jerry Convertion is from ".." to ``.."

Comment: I think the reason some people (including me) got confused is because you didn't use inline code formatting (backticks) in the question.  In a monospaced font it's easy to see that the final "quote" is really two apostrophes (`''`), but all I saw was `"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing quotation marks with "\`\`" and "''"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967033/replacing-quotation-marks-with-and)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused by your approach. Shouldn't it be the other way round with ``` s/``/"[a-z]/g ```? But then, I think it'll be better with:

```
s/``(.*?)''/"\1"/g
```

`(.*?)` captures what's between ``` `` ``` and `''`.

`\1` contains this capture.

---

If it's the opposite that you're looking for (i.e. I wrongly interpreted your question), then I would suggest this:

```
s/"(.*?)"/``\1''/g
```

Which works on the same principles as the previous regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to tackle multiple quotations, replacing all `"` in one step.

```
echo '"Quote" she said, "again."' | sed "s/\"\([^\"]*\)\"/\`\`\1''/g"
```

The `[^\"]*` avoids the need for ungreedy matching, [which does not seem possible in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed).

Comment: Be careful when dealing with escaped `"` or other occurences of `"` which are not meant to be quotation marks, e.g. as in `"Quote" she said na\"ively, "again."`. These are party poopers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **TeXmaker** software, you could use a regular expression with the *Replace* command (CTRL+R), and put the following into the *Find* field:

```
"([^}]*)"
```

and into the *Replace* field:

```
``$1''
```

And then just press the *Replace All* button. But after that, you still have to check that everything is fine, and maybe you need to do some corrections. This has worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping the word:

```
sed 's/"\([a-z]\)/``\1/'
```

On my PC:

```
abhishekm71@PC:~$ echo \"hello\" | sed 's/"\([a-z]\)/``\1/'
``hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on your input file (are quotes always paired, or can there be ommissions?). I suggest the following robust approach:

```
sed 's/"\([0-9a-zA-Z]\)/``\1/g'
sed "s/\([0-9a-zA-Z]\)\"/\1\'\'/g"
```

Assumption: An opening quotation mark is always immediately followed by a letter or digit, a closing quotation mark is preceeded by one. Quotations can span over several words an even several input lines (some of the other solutions don't work when this happens).

Note that I also replace the closing quotation mark: Depending on the fonts you use the double quotation mark can be typeset as neutral straight quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something contained in straight quotation marks *not containing a quotation mark*, so the best regex is `"([^"]*?)"`. Replace it with  ``` ``\1'' ```. In Perl this can be simplified to ``` s/"([^"]*?)"/``\1''/g ```. I would be very careful with this approach, it only works if all opening quotation marks have matching closing ones, for example in `"one" two "three" four`. But it will fail in `"one" t"wo "three" four` producing  ``` ``one'' t``wo ''three" ```.